# .gitconfig global remote URL to switch from GitHub to GitLab

Tags: git, github, configuration, gitlab, git-config

Switching from github to gitlab. Imported all my repos.

Now I want to continue pushing my code only to gitlab. How do I make this happen?

I updated my `.gitconfig` file to use this, but it didn't change anything:

```
[url "git@gitlab.com/"]
    insteadOf = git@github.com/
```

Comment: This actually worked for me, but the path in gitlab can significantly differ from path on github (depending on specific migration details). Also, don't forget to add `Host gitlab.com` into `~/.ssh/config` file (refer [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html#configure-ssh-to-point-to-a-different-directory)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a git repo on GitLab? 
Your `url = <url to your git repo>` should be pointing to an existing git repo. Also `git@github.com` couldn't possibly be your git repo. 
Anyway, just make a repo on GitLab and point that url in your `.gitconfig`

You can follow [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-project.html) tutorial to make a new project on GitLab. After that copy the url from the browser into the `.gitconfig`. (add a .git extension to the end)

Comment: I'm trying to set a global URL so that I won't have to set it for each project :)

Comment: but I'm realizing I probably need to do that. So I'll accept your answer

Comment: Thanks. BTW, I'm not sure if setting a global URL for every git repo you have is what git does. Aren't they going to be many different projects in many different directories?

Comment: Perhaps not. This was a global .gitconfig file, so I was under the impression that was something I could do. Now that I think about it, it probably doesn't make sense